# How to create a popup window in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am new to using Dart.  I was wonder how do I create a pop-up window based on an event? i know how to create the event but not sure how to create the pop-up window.

```dart
void main()
{
  List<Element> radioButtons = queryAll(".requestType");
  Iterator i = radioButtons.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext)
  {
    var item = i.next();
    item.on.click.add(addRequestTypeEvent);
  }
}

void addRequestTypeEvent(Event event) {
    <POPUP WINDOW>
}
```

Update 01/17/2013: I figured out how to do it.

```
 window.open("http://www.yahoo.com", "yahoo", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [Window.open](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Window.html#open):

```dart
window.open(url, name);
```

You can read more on what `options` you can give as third parameter on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open).

One more thing, you can simplify your code. The following does the same :

```dart
void main()
{
  final radioButtons = queryAll(".requestType");

  // with forEach method
  radioButtons.forEach((item) => item.on.click.add(addRequestTypeEvent));

  // with for loop
  for (final item in radioButtons) {
    item.on.click.add(addRequestTypeEvent);
  }
}
```

Comment: the popup window would display another page. So i don't think that would work.

Comment: Answer updated. You should perhaps be more accurate in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally figured it out.

Comment: It would be even better if you validate my answer :)